# How to handle username/pass changes in a distributed REST application?

Tags: rest, https, distributed-computing

I have a distributed REST application, written in C++, with an integrated SQLite DB. The application is self contained - no apache or iis server, and no external mysql. The application is the logic behind a hardware sensor: the application monitors sensor(s), identifying and storing data of interest, and generating "events" when data of interest repeats. The creation of data of interest is synchronized across the Internet to multiple instances of the application using REST to communicate the synchronization.

Using basic authentication over https, each instance maintains a local key/value store of remote instances' user/pass authentication data. This is necessary because each communication with a remote instance of the application requires authentication.

My question is **how to handle the situation when the human operator changes either the username or password in the application, while the application is in active synchronization with remote instances.**

I'm thinking this is really no different than any other material application data changing - when a local username / password changes, a REST communication is posted to each synchronization instance containing the changed data for that remote's local key/value store. Any communications that fail get queued for when that remote is back, as that is material information the remote needs to maintain synchronization.

Because the communications occur over https, the fact that authentication data is being passed around is okay.

I thought I might need special logic to handle the race condition where one instance tries to communicate with another, but the other has just changed its authentication fields. The sender will queue with my current logic, and when the remote sends it's updated authentication data, the locally queued failed communications will start succeeding. So that does not appear to be an issue.

I guess **this is a request for anyone that's been here before, what did you do?** Maybe my search terms are weak here, because I'm not finding discussion of this issue.